# Why does this simple code not run correctly in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have wrote a piece of code that determine the stimulus situation based on what the user input, But the problem is that it gives same  output always and that is not correct according to the Rules down.
this is my code :

```
 start:- readenviroment(X),check(X,SS),environment(X,SS),write(SS).


readenviroment(X):-
write("What sort of environment is a trainee dealing with on the job?"),nl,
read(X).

environment(X,SS):-
    visual(X,SS) ; verbal(X,SS).

visual(X,SS):-
((X == pictures ; X == illustrations ; X == photographs ; X== diagrams)->assert(yes(SS,cars))).

verbal(X,SS):-
((X == papers ; X == manuals ; X == documents ; X == textbooks )->assert(yes(SS,verbal))).


:- dynamic yes/2.
check(XX,SS):-
verify(XX,SS),!.

verify(XX,SS):-
yes(XX,SS)->true.
```

And this is the Output:

```
     2 ?- start.
What sort of environment is a trainee dealing with on the job?
|: textbook.
verbal
true.

3 ?- start.
What sort of environment is a trainee dealing with on the job?
|: diagram.

false.

4 ?- start.
What sort of environment is a trainee dealing with on the job?
|: diagrams.
verbal
true.
```

According to these two rules.

```
Rule 1:
if the environment is papers
or the environment is manuals
or the environment is documents
or the environment is textbooks
then stimulus_situation is verbal
Rule 2:
if the environment is pictures
if the environment is illustrations
if the environment is photographs
if the environment is diagrams
then stimulus_situation is visual
```

Can anyone help me please?! Also thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where/how are these rules encoded?  They refer to things that do not appear in the code.

Comment: @ScottHunter these Rules are encode with visual and verbal functions.

Comment: Nothing in the posted code refers to papers, manuals, documents, textbooks, pictures, illustrations, photographs, or diagrams.

Comment: @ScottHunter Wait two minutes please.

Comment: @ScottHunter Check my Edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with your code. The direct problem is that `check/2` is called before `environment/2`.

But it does not seem to me that you have an understanding of the Prolog interpreter works. For example, the variable `SS` is never bound to anything anywhere in your code.

You can start by modeling your rules as follows:

```
env_stim(Env, verbal) :- member(Env, [paper, manuals, documents, textbooks])
env_stim(Env, visual) :- member(Env, <etc>).
<etc>.
```

Then you just ask the user for the `Env` variable, call `env_stim(Env, Stim)` and write out the response:

```
start :- 
  writeln('What is the environment?'), 
  read(Env), 
  env_stim(Env, Stim), 
  writeln(Stim).
```